# Parallel processing in Flow is not parallel?

Tags: elixir

I have a following simple module.

```
defmodule Flow.F1 do
  def t1 do
    ["one", "two", "three"]
    |> Flow.from_enumerable()
    |> Flow.map(&p1(&1))
    |> Flow.partition()
    |> Enum.to_list()
  end

  defp p1(item) do
    IO.puts("Processing #{item}")
    :timer.sleep(2000)
    IO.puts("Processed #{item}")
    String.upcase(item)
  end
end
```

Now when running Flow.F1.t1() I'm getting this result:

```
Processing one
Processed one
Processing two
Processed two
Processing three
Processed three
["TWO", "ONE", "THREE"]
```

Processing takes 6 seconds as it waits 2sec in each P1 call, but I would expect (from documentation) that `Elixir.map` is processing items in parallel. So we should see something like:

```
Processing one
Processing two
Processing three
Processed one
Processed two
Processed three
```

And should take 2sec only. Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow work with batches of 500 items, as stated in the [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html).

I think your input data is not enough to flow splits it into more than one consumer, so only one consumer is taking all the work.
If you add the option `max_demand: 1` to your `Flow.from_enumerable` it will consume in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, it really did the job. And Flow.partition can be omitted in this example.